# Valgrind wrapper with varargs?

Tags: valgrind

I think that the wrapper framework in valgrind is pretty nice.  I am trying to track differences between different code paths (as to why one works and another does not).  Instead of trying to look at a difference of an `strace` output (which will not give me all details I need because I want to trace lib and sys calls I decided to use wrappers around a handful of functions.

The one function that got me scratching my head is `fcntl`.

The fcntl manpage declares it as follows

```
int fcntl(int fd, int cmd);
int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, long arg);
int fcntl(int fd, int cmd, struct flock *lock);
```

However as this is `C` and overloading does not come naturally to `C`, it is prototyped as follows in `fcntl.h`

```
extern int fcntl (int __fd, int __cmd, ...);
```

The end-user wrapping facility in valgrind supports N number of WORD arguments, but carries a warning about using the wrong number of args and I did not see a mention of any varargs.

A more classical varargs function like `printf` is typically implemented with a lower fixed args function `vprintf` which takes `va_list` as a single parameter.  In such a case I would have wrapped `vprintf` rather than `printf`, but alas AFAIK `fcntl` does not have such an intermediate function.

My question is - **what would a "safe" wrapper for `fcntl` look like?**

For example, the following **seems** to work, but is it safe:

```
int I_WRAP_SONAME_FNNAME_ZU(libcZdsoZa,fcntl)(int fd, int cmd, ...)
{
  int result;
  OrigFn fn;
  void* arg;

  va_list argp;
  va_start(argp, cmd);
  arg=va_arg(argp, void*);

  VALGRIND_GET_ORIG_FN(fn);
  printf("@@fcntl wrapper: args fd=%d, cmd=%d, arg=%p ... ", fd, cmd, arg);
  CALL_FN_W_WWW(result, fn, fd, cmd, arg);
  printf("##fcntl wrapper: result %d\n", result);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look syswrappers for sys_ioctl in valgrind sources in file coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-linux.c.

Look at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-missing.html for details.

Maybe you will need to rebuild valgrind with your changes for syswrappers.